# Connecting to the Wolfram Engine from C++

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have created a test application to connect to the wolfram engine based on the documentation. I don't know if i'm right but reading LLU (Library Link Utilities) seems solve that problem by providing some WSTP capabilities with a WSStream class. My problem is i don't seem to understand how WSStream class should be used for example to calculate 2+2.

My program looks like the following:

```
int main()
{
    // WSTP Initialise
    WSENV env = WSInitialize((char*)0);
    if (env == (WSENV)0)
    {
       std::cout << "Unable to initialize!";
       return 1;
    }
    else
       std::cout << "Iniialized!";

    // WSTP Open a connection to the wolfram kernel
    int error;
    WSLINK link;
    link = WSOpenString(env, " -linklaunch \"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram Engine\\13.3\\mathkernel.exe\"", &error);

    if(link == (WSLINK)0 || error != WSEOK)
    {
       std::cout << "Unable to create link!";
       return 1;
    }
    else
       std::cout << "Link created!";

    // WSTP Activate link
    if (!WSActivate(link))
    {
       std::cout << "Link not activated!";
       return 1;
    }
    else
       std::cout << "Link activated!";
    // Data exchange -->> MyProblem
    std::cout << "Create the stream object" << std::endl;
    LLU::WSStream<LLU::WS::Encoding::UTF8, LLU::WS::Encoding::UTF8> test(link);
    std::cout << "Add 2+2 to the stream" << std::endl;
    test << (mint) 1 << LLU::WS::BeginExpr::BeginExpr("1") << "2+2" << LLU::WS::EndExpr();
    std::cout << "Wait for a reply" << std::endl;
    int result;
    test >> result;
    cout << "Hello CMake. Error : " << error << " Result : " << result << endl;
    std::cout << "Close the connection..." << std::endl;

    // WSTP Close gracefully
    WSClose(link);
    WSDeinitialize(env);
    return 0;
}
```

When I start I have to select the *.exe with the wolfram kernel. and it shows the link is activated. However the program get's stuck when receiving the result from the calculation, it exits. Probably because I'm not using the right call convention for the data exchange part. Does any one know how this should be done ?

I've tried to look in the sources of WSStream.hpp and tried to send and receive different objects. But that's a long shot.